# VsCode setup for showing errors

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-hooks

I'm learning React right now and I would like to know how to setup my VsCode so that it shows me an error when I forget to add dependencies in useCallback or useEffect hooks

Comment: It depends on your setup. If you use an already configured and updated setup (like create-react-app) the only thing you should need it's the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint extension

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **javascript** or **typescript** for your react project?

To show errors/warnings in VSCode as you type, you will need to install an [**ESLint extension** for vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint).

Once you have the ESLint extension, you will need to setup your ESLint rules.
Create-react-app (which you are probably using to create your project) already comes with some ESLint rules. You can see the enabled rules in your **node_modules/eslint-config-react-app**

Now you may want to extend / add rules or plugins to your ESLint ruleset.
You can do this without [ejecting](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) your react app. [Here's some information on configuring it.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config)

A simple eslintConfig section for **typescript** to start you off looks like this:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "extends": [
          "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
        ],
        "files": [
          "**/*.ts?(x)"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Currently using javascript. Typescript comes later in the course. I have eslint instaled but for some reason it's not showing me warnings

Comment: I added eslint extension in VsCode and it works now. Thank you!